# Does each load in a three-phase balanced load consume the same average power which they get from three-phase voltage sources?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Assume three-phase balanced loads in Δ or Y configuration connected to three-phase AC voltage sources in a Y configuration.

Does each load in three-phase loads consume equal average power? Assume symmetry of voltage sources and loads and voltage sources being in a positive phase sequence. Does each load have the same impedance?

Comment: But the load in a 3 phase system is made of 3 single phase loads...

Comment: You're answering your own question; at the end you say "Does each load have the same impedance" but you further constrain the question by saying "balanced load"/"assume symmetry of...loads"

Comment: Yes. I saw a problem in a book which says three phase balanced loads which I interpreted as three equal impedances implying they consume same power . Then I saw another problem in which in three phase balanced loads,  the loads consume unequal power. This seemed like a contradiction. Which is the correct way to think about three phase balanced loads?

Answer (score 0):

> *Assume symmetry of voltage sources and loads and voltage sources being
> in a positive phase sequence. Does each load have the same impedance?*

A balanced, 3-phase load has equal impedance for each of the three individual limbs.

> *Does each load in three-phase loads consume equal average power?*

If the supply is balanced and the load is balanced then yes

<sub>But, you can't rule out imbalances in both that conspire in such a way to produce equal power in all three limbs.</sub>

> *Does each load in a three phase balanced load consume same average
> power which they get from three phase voltage sources?*

Only when the supply is balanced.